# Aligning an h2 and a link next to it by using floats doesn't work

Tags: css

I am trying to align a header and a link next to each other, but somehow this fails. This is the code:

```
<h2>whatever</h2>
<a href="">link</a>
```

I tried using `float: left` on both of them, but that failed. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Floating should work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x7etx/

Answer (score 2):

By default `h2` has `block` as its `display` value. Changing it to `inline` will do the trick.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJbmC

```
h2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Float works. But `h2` by default applies margin.
Try this:

```
h2
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48zhF/

Answer (score 0):

try `display: inline-block;`

```
h2 { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

EDIT: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MM8ry/)